# When should a class implement an interface?

Tags: typescript, interface, interface-implementation

Working on a project and seeing developers doing the following in typescript.

```
    export class Ledger implements ILedger {
      LedgerID: number;
      CashAmmount: number;
      Units: number;

      public static someFunction {
        // an ajax call for example to a controller
      }
    }

    export interface ILedger {
       LedgerID: number;
       CashAmmount: number;
       Units: number;
     }
```

Wondering if its the right way of doing things. Just seems pointless if there is no implementation in the class. Then in our React components there are references to the interface or sometimes the class. Want to start setting up some conventions but wanted some help on what the proper practice is in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems pointless if there is no implementation in the class.

I agree. No need in that case. But there are valid cases

## Dependency inject

Something like : https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

## Conforming to *external Apis*

Someone asks for `IFoo`. You want to use a class in your code base for `IFoo`. Have a class extend it so you know that the class always follows that external IFoo.